# Ruby, evaluate one ruby function or another using the same DO block

Tags: ruby, haml, erb, syntactic-sugar

In ERB or HAML, I need to be able to evaluate one function, or a different one, based on the output of a conditional, while using the same HTML block for either one.

In HAML, it would like something like this:

```
- is_a = @thing.is_a?
= (is_a ? f.method_a : f.method_b) arg_1, |block_arg1| do
  #thing
    .blah
    .inner-thing
      = block_arg1.some_method
```

Notice how, on line 2 of my pseudocode, I am trying to evaluate either one function, or the other, based upon a conditional.  But I need pass the same arguments to either, especially since I don't want to have to re-type the DO block.

Maybe I could avoid that problem ("I don't want to re-type...") by making that DO block a named function?  How does one turn a HAML or ERB block into a named Ruby function?

I'm using Ruby-on-Rails 4.  Not that it matters; this looks like more of a ruby syntax question than a framework question.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for #send

```
- is_a = @thing.is_a?
= f.send(is_a ? :method_a : :method_b, arg_1) do |block_arg|
  (...)
```